# real time collaboration in google colaboratory

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

Looking for a way to enable real time collaboration in a classroom setting while using Google Colaboratory for a IPython NoteBook. I know I can share the notebook, perform some operations etc, but not sure how to see my collaborators contributions in real time.

Halp?

edit 1:
I imagined a scenario where one student group could input their code for one part of a problem, while a second student group could do the same, and both would be able to see what the other was doing at 1 minute intervals or so.

Comment: Sorry, it looks like [the realtime sync API is being turned off](https://developers.google.com/realtime/deprecation).

Comment: Jupyterlab is working on this: https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/5382

Answer (score 7):

I'm going to more nicely phrase what has been discussed in the comments by Mr. Smith and Alaonde, but further elaborate on it for clarification:

The feature of Google Colab that allowed for edits to be made in real time by multiple users, has been shut down. I'm not entirely sure as to why, but I can assume it has to do with the amount of resources required on Google's end in order to keep Colaboratory free for all. However I did some searching and there are a few alternatives, though I doubt their as easy to use or as user friendly as Colaboratory:

1. [Jupyter Notebooks (Needs no introduction)](https://jupyter.org/)
2. [Azure Notebooks (Microsoft Product)](https://notebooks.azure.com/#)
3. [Apache Zeppelin (Similar to Jupyter Notebooks)](http://zeppelin.apache.org/)

Hopefully I was at least a little helpful!

Comment: https://codecollab.io worked for me and it is really good for simple codes.

Comment: datalore.jetbrains.com worked for me and my team.

Answer (score 2):

The only good tool for real time coding collaboration I know of is https://deepnote.com